# What is CKNotification.NotificationType 0?

Tags: ios, push-notification, cloudkit

My app uses CoreData & CloudKit sync via a `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`.
To be notified as fast as possible when an iCloud record changes or when iCloud sharing changes, the app has the following subscriptions:

```
let subscriptionCD_Items = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: iCloudRecordTypeCD_Item,
                                               predicate: NSPredicate(value: true),
                                               subscriptionID: kICloudPrivateDatabaseSubscriptionCD_ItemChangesID,
                                               options: [.firesOnRecordCreation, .firesOnRecordUpdate, .firesOnRecordDeletion])
```

and

```
let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: kICloudSharedDatabaseSubscriptionID)
```

The app receives correctly the corresponding notifications of type `.query` and `.database`.

However, it also receives notifications of **type 0**:

```
<CKNotification: 0x17a7a360; notificationType=0, notificationID=<CKNotificationID: 0x1653cab0; UUID=ce92f96e-79e8-4ec9-96cc-8558ec98de44>, containerID=<CKContainerID: 0x165e9b90; containerIdentifier=iCloud.com.zeh4soft.shop, containerEnvironment="Sandbox">, subscriptionOwnerUserRecordID=<CKRecordID: 0x17a9dfe0; recordName=_3d1fa9780ef6c62eb6477944b2db3b14, zoneID=_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__>>
```

This type 0 is not mentioned in the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/cknotification/notificationtype).

What does it mean?

Comment: The public header file only has values 1, 2, 3, and 4 corresponding to the 4 documented types.

Comment: What action on the other device is triggering the notification?

Comment: @johnelemans As far as I remember (it did not happen again) I manually updated an iCloud record in the dashboard to test if the push notification was handled right. I will update my question when it happens again.